# Integrating a function with quadratic relation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ is a function satisfying $$f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + {x^2}f(x) = 0$$ for all non zero $x$, then help in finding $$\int_{\sin\theta}^{cosec\theta} f(x)dx $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$I=\int_{\sin t}^{\csc t}f(x)dx$$
Substitute $x=\frac{1}{z}$
We get:
$$I=-\int_{\csc t}^{\sin t}\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$$
$$\implies I=\int_{\sin t}^{\csc t}\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$$
Adding it to the original integral gives $I=0$